# Android Studio How can i change by Activity the name of navigation-drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, uinavigationbar, navigation-drawer

I have this Navigation-drawer and I want to change the name "Usuario" by Activity, but when i put this code and compile the app, this app closes.

[image]

```
final TextView Name_nav = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Name_nav);
    Name_nav.setText(name);
```

When Name_nav is the textView's name from the nav_header_main.xml, thx to your help

Comment: You need to post exception stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That view you gave as header of NavigationView. So First you should get that header View from NavigationView(`view = navView.getHeaderView(0);`)

From that view you should get the text view and do modiciation

Ex:

```
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
final TextView Name_nav = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.Name_nav);
```